# Multiple keys vs dictionary in memcache?

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

What is a better approach? Having multiple keys or having a dictionary?

In my scenario I want to store songs in a country basis and cache that for further access later on. Below I write the rough pseudocode without disclosing too many details to keep it simple. The actual songs will most probably be IDs from songs in a database.

Many keys approach

```
cache.set("songs_from_city1", city1_songs)
cache.set("songs_from_city2", city2_songs)
..
```

Dictionary approach

```
cache.set("songs_by_city", {
  'city1': city1_songs
  'city2': city2_songs
  ..
})
..
```

Comment: That really depends on your requirements. I'd assume that as far as setup goes, setting multiple values at once would be more efficient, but extracting them back might not be. Maybe the best way would be to use `set_many` which is basically a more efficient way of doing method one with one command

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment it mainly depends on the application requirement.

To Add another perspective,

You can think of it as the problem of 'storing and retrieve 1 object vs multiple granular objects'. There is a detailed discussion on this tradeoff in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455922/store-single-big-object-in-memcached-vs-multiple-keys/45482038#45482038).

Hope it helps!